# Display value from url params in dropdown upon page load or URL change

Tags: html, angular

I have a website where the url provides some parameters such as `page?&animal=bear` so there's a `request` object that includes the field animal.

Animal on the website are presented as dropdowns. I want the dropdown to display bear as the selected value when the page loads. Another feature I must have is to preserve [disabled] on some of the options.

The closest I've gotten, following Angular paradigms, was setting [ngValue] instead of [value]. Only when I click on the dropdown to expand, the dropdown will open to the ngModel's value, but I want the dropdown to display ngModel's value when the page loads.

The current, best-working state I've gotten is a bit hacky. I force the ngModel's value as the first and thus displayed option, but the tradeoff is that the option is displayed twice. I don't want that. See the following code:

```html
<select id="animal" name="animal" materialize="formSelect"                                                   [(ngModel)]="request.animal">
    <option [value]="request.animal" [selected]="true"> {{request.animal }} </option>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let animal of animals">
            <option *ngIf="config.availableAnimals.includes(animal.name)"                                 [value]="animal.name">{{ animal.name }}</option>
            <option *ngIf="!config.availableCountries.includes(animal.name)"
                                  [value]="animal.name" disabled>{{ animal.name }}</option>
         </ng-container>
</select>
```

Controller:

```js
constructor(...) {
    this.request = {
        animal = '',
        continent = ''
    };

    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((param: Params) => {
             if (location.href.includes('?')) {
                 this.request.animal = param.animal;
                 this.request.continent =  param.continent;
                 console.log("url params are changed");
                 console.log(this.request);
                 this.sendRequest();
             }
         });
    }

  public async sendRequest() {
     if (location.href.includes('?')) {
        location.href += '?animal=' + this.request.animal +
                '&continent=' + this.request.continent +
        }
        await this.clearResponses();
     //calls other functions to get data 
  }
```

What I ultimately want is that when the page loads or when the URL changes, the animal.name is displayed as the selected item on the dropdown, without any duplicated options showing up.

Thanks

Comment: Where's your controller code?

Comment: added with my controller code

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ngValue on your options instead of value. Then you need an ngModel on your select bound to a property that you set to request.animal.

```
<select id="animal" name="animal" [(ngModel)]="selectedAnimal"
```

and in you ngOnInit

```
selectedAnimal = request.animal;
```

Also that logic of *ngIf="config.availableAnimals.includes(animal.name)" is bad practice. You should create your animals array with a disabled property.

```
[disabled]="animal.disabled"
```

Comment: Do I need to do anything with [selected]?

Comment: No if you are two way binding it will automagically be selected

Comment: So for the option tag, it should look like <option *ngFor="let animal of animals" [disabled]=animal.disabled" [ngValue]="animal"> {{ animal.name }}" ?